# how to use if rule in jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, conditional-statements

Hi I have a simple modal popup which has 3 name fields and 3 e mail fields adjacent to each other. I am new to jQuery so can any one please help me how to write a logic for the following case?

The first name field and Email field are mandatory so I kept the class as required fields but the other two name and e-mail fields are optional but if I enter a value in name field I have to enter the value in Email field. In other words if name field is not empty email field should not be empty. Please let me know if some one can help me thank you.

**The jQuery code is as follows its getting data from ajax**

```
function shareWithAFriend(itemId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "shareWithAFriend.do?itemId="+itemId,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(html) {
                $("#tellInfoPop").html(html);
                $("#itemId").val(itemId);
                $("#emailFriend").validate({
                    errorClass: "formError",
                    errorContainer: "#referAFriendFormError",
                    errorLabelContainer: "#referAFriendFormError",
                    onfocusout: false,
                    wrapper: 'li',
                    messages: {
                        referName01: {
                            required: "<@spring.message "referAFriend.error.nameRequired"/>"
                        },
                        referEmail01: {
                            required: "<@spring.message "referAFriend.error.emailRequired"/>",
                            email: "<@spring.message "referAFriend.error.emailFormat"/>"
                        },
                        referEmail02: {
                            email: "<@spring.message "referAFriend.error.emailFormat"/>"
                        },
                        referEmail03: {
                            email: "<@spring.message "referAFriend.error.emailFormat"/>"
                        },
                        securityKey: {
                            required: "<@spring.message "referAFriend.error.securityRequired"/>"
                        }
                    },
                    groups: {
                        emailGroup: "referEmail01 referEmail02 referEmail03"
                    },
```

THE Html code is as fallows

```
<div class="leftCol">
        <label for="emailToName1" class="formLabel"><span class="required">*</span>Name:</label>
      <div><input type="text" id="emailToName1" name="referName01" value="${referAFriendBean.referName01!}" class="required" tabindex="1" /></div>
      <div class="pad5Top"><input type="text" id="emailToName2" name="referName02" value="${referAFriendBean.referName02!}" tabindex="3" /></div>
      <div class="pad5Top"><input type="text" id="emailToName3" name="referName03" value="${referAFriendBean.referName03!}" tabindex="5" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="rightCol">
        <label for="emailToAddress1" class="formLabel"><span class="required">*</span>Email address:</label>
      <div><input type="text" id="emailToAddress1" name="referEmail01" value="${referAFriendBean.referEmail01!}" class="required email" tabindex="2" /></div>
      <div class="pad5Top"><input type="text" id="emailToAddress2" name="referEmail02" class="email" tabindex="4" value="${referAFriendBean.referEmail02!}" /></div>
      <div class="pad5Top"><input type="text" id="emailToAddress3" name="referEmail03" class="email" tabindex="6" value="${referAFriendBean.referEmail03!}" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add an event handler for your optional name element that will dynamically add or remove required class for address.

I don't know if I'm picking the right ids here, but you should get the idea:

```
$('#emailToName2').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $('#emailToAddress2').addClass('required');
    } else {
        $('#emailToAddress2').removeClass('required');
    }
});
```

or even shorted version but may be less readable if you are new to jQuery

```
$('#emailToName2').keyup(function () {
    $('#emailToAddress2').toggleClass('required', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: hey rayell how can i give you a check mark and can you tell me if there is any way i can write the same code in rules: insted of using the key up function.

Comment: You should see the check mark just below this answer votes. Just click it. I'm not sure how to rewrite this code in order to make it work with jQuery validate rules. The problem is that those rules work well when one field validation doesn't depend on other field value. In fact my solution doesn't add anything to validation, it just adds or removes one extra validation rule to a field on keyup event. I'm sorry, but I don't any way to make it simpler then that.